# Bourbaki Proof in First Consequences? Use of Not?

Tags: logic, math-history, proof-theory, alternative-set-theories

In Bourbaki Theory of Sets English (c) 1970 Section 3.2 C6 there is a first consequence that I have questions about.  I have attached images of the text here.  My question is:

- We are told that A, B, C are are relations in Theory.  So $\vdash A, B, C$.  How can "not A" be substituted into S4 when it is not defined yet as a true relation of the theory or axiom?  Is $\vdash \lnot A$ added as a step in this proof?
- Where does Bourbaki define what "not A" is?  I have only found use regarding the symbol $\lnot$ on Page 24 Section 2 and that is all up to the point of this first consequence.

I am new to proof theory, however understand how the substitutions lead to the conclusion.  I'm just concerned about the above being properly defined.

Thanks

[C6 Proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Go3z4.png)
[Axioms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdd8E.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> We are told that $A, B, C$ are are relations in Theory. So $⊢A,B,C$. How can "not $A$" be substituted into S4 when it is not defined yet as a true relation of the theory or axiom?

In Bourbaki's text, *relations* [i.e. *assemblies of second species*, §1.3] are formulas .

And see §2.2. : "A *theorem* in $\mathscr T$ is a relation *which appears in a proof of* $\mathscr T$".

Theorem C.6 asserts that "$A,B,C$ are *relations* in $\mathscr T$", i.e. formulas of the theory and not theorems.

S4 : $(A \to B) \to ((C \lor A) \to (C \lor B))$ is an *axiom schema*; thus, every instance of it is valid (a *tautology*).

This means that we can freely substitute the schematic letters : $A,B,C$ with *formulas* : again, the poof does not assume that $\lnot A$ is a theorem of $\mathscr T$.

> Where does Bourbaki define what "not $A$" is?

See §1.4.CF2 : "If $A$ is a relation in a theory $\mathscr T$, then $\lnot A$ is a relation in $\mathscr T$.